# Are materialized views read only in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

According to the official documentation of create view (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-createview.html):

Currently, views are read only: the system will not allow an insert, update, or delete on a view.

In the official documentation of create materialized view (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-creatematerializedview.html) it is not mentioned if a materialized view is read only or not.

So are materialized views in Postgresql read only?

Comment: I have no real experience with PostgreSQL, but fortunately it's [easily tested](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=f9f3303df150da9eee74a0abeb12a9e2). (You can experiment with versions there as well, though not as far back as 9.2.) (Some) views have become updatable since 9.2; materialized views are not even in 13.

Comment: First of all what version of Postgres are you using? 9.2 is ~4 years past EOL and the documentation link for views no longer applies. See latest production version 13 [View](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html). As to materialized views they are read only.

Comment: Your reference is from 9.2. Is that really the version you are asking about? Currently views are not read only. Materialized views (currently) can be read-only, updatable or writable (check FOR UPDATE).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks! The one I was looking at was indeed an old documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, materialized views can be read-only, updatable or writable.

Comment: Is that missing a "not"?

Comment: You might want to mention that they are [`REFRESH`able](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html) though